# MySQL random row from rows which have a certain value

Tags: mysql

I know that I can retrieve a random row from a table using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM rows ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

But I only want to select rows which have the column `used` set to 'no'.

Do I have to use a subquery or is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Any basic, introductory book or tutorial on sql will likely prove enlightening

Comment: Just add `WHERE` clause to the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE used = 'no'
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```